# Pass data from html webresource window in MS Dynamics CRM

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online, webresource

I need to pass data (an array of strings) from html webresource window to the form. Please note, **window** means **window** (it is *NOT* embedded in CRM form, is *NOT* a dialog, it is a window opened from the form). I used Xrm.Utility.openWebResource. I need either to influence fields on the form or call a js function on the form. Any help is appreciated.

P.S. "onunload" is ignored by Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. Invoking a function from child in parent by `window.opener` is feasible. Also you need Json library to serialize/deserialize so that objects can be sent between windows.

In CRM parent window:

```
function openWebResource() {   
    var popupWindow = Xrm.Utility.openWebResource(...);
}

function callFunction(myObjects) {
    var entity = JSON.parse(myObjects);

    if (entity) {
           var value = new Array();
           value[0] = new Object();
           value[0].id = entity.Id;
           value[0].Name = entity.Name;

       // do your logic here
    }
}
```

In popup window (web resource):

```
function callParent() {
    var entity = {};
    entity.Id = 1;
    entity.Name = “test”;

    var arr = JSON.stringify(entity);
    window.opener.callFunction(arr);
}
```